# Suministro Inmediato Informacion

Tags: vb.net, aeat-sii

Soy nuevo en `Visual` y estoy con el tema del SII.

Poco a poco voy avanzando. Se envía certificado, instanciar las clases de las facturas (que me ha costado lo suyo).

Ahora me informa del error:

> ```
> Código[4102] el XML no cumple con el esquema. Falta informar campo obligatorio NIF
> ```

Según veo en las clases del web service en la clase contraparte existe una property ítem que informa de `IDOtro` ( país y tipo id ) y NIF. Esta propiedad es de tipo object y no veo forma de instanciarla y pasarle datos.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esta pregunta necesitaba mas información.
Con la poca información que ofreces, simplemente puedo decir que en el apartado de Contraparte estás obligado a poner un NIF, o bien un IDOtro

Si el proveedor es español, utiliza el campo NIF
Si el proveedor no es español, tendrás que usar el apartado IDOtro, en el que tendrás que entrar IDType + ID

ID = Número de identificación

IDType debe ser un valor a seleccionar entre:

```
02 NIF/IVA
03 PASAPORTE
04 DOCUMENTO OFICIAL DE IDENTIFICACIÓN EXPEDIDO POR EL PAIS O TERRITORIO DE RESIDENCIA
05 CERTIFICADO DE RESIDENCIA
06 OTRO DOCUMENTO PROBATORIO 07 NO CENSADO
```